# Custom Layout not detecting in mainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am a beginner at android.

I am using `Android Studio 1.0`. I am trying to make a `custom layout` for `listView`. I created custom layout files in the `res/layout named row_layout`. xml for layout is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cl_textView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code to implement that custom layout in the MainActivity class is:

```
  ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.row_layout,toDoList);
```

But activity class doesn't detect this custom layout and shows the error below while building.

[image]

Comment: remove `android.R.layout.row_layout` and use `R.layout.row_layout`.

Comment: Ah!HA! There you solved it bro thank you very much for the prompt response. I was following a tutorial and it was android.R.layout.row_layout there. What's the difference can you elaborate kindly.

Comment: android sdk has its own layout for listview. to use them you need to call `android.R` and for your own custom views are registered in `R.java` file in `Gen[Generated Java Files]` to use them you only need to call is as `R.layout.views`.

Comment: Great thanks cleared my confusion.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha, if your problem is solved, please mark one of the clear answer as correct.

Comment: @sufiyan There you go. Thanks :) I was getting confused on which one to approve. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.layout` denotes the resources which are provided by your application. All the variables, resource files (drawable, string, layout etc) which are defined by your application can be accessed by `R`.

Example `R.layout.*, r.drawable.*, R.id.*, R.color.* etc`

But `android.R` denotes the resources of your android SDK. all the resources which are not defined by you but are defined by android SDK will be available to you if you use `android.R`

In your code, you are using your own layout so replace `android.R.layout` with `R.layout`

Comment: +100 for brief explanation about the difference of `R.layout` and `android.R.layout`

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace the `android.R.` with `R.` because `R.*` provides your application resources instead, `android.R.*` provides resources that ship with the Android SDK.
( `R.*` is actually shortcut for `your.package.R.*` )

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

**It should be:**

```
ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout,toDoList);
```

`android.R` refers to those resources pre-built in the android sdk.

Since you have defined your own layout for the custom list view, you should use R file generated in your project.